# Streaming images from directory and associating prediction with file name in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a trained model and I need to run inference on a large directory of images. I know I can make a generator using ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory but it is not obvious how to associate predicted results with file names. Ideally given a keras model + directory of images i'd like to have an array of file names and predicted probabilities. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to separate the images into a different folder, corresponding to the class. The name of the folder should be the name of the class, by using the `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` Keras will automatically infer the class names based on the directories. 
As an example, you should have a folder named "data" that contains 2 folders named "cat" and "dog".

Then you can call the method `ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory("path/to/folder/data")` and Keras will produce a dataset with the two classes, "cat" and "dog".

Depending on the name of the files, the separation might be easy for you with a simple program, If not, I recommend using a program that groups together similar images, and based on that you can manually create the folders.

Comment: I am doing inference, not training. There is no known class names. What I would like to do is map something like:

0034503245.jpg -> [0.34, 0.1, 0.56] 

etc...

So for every filename in directory I want to record probability distribution over classes inferenced by the model. This will then allow me to select certain files for further processing. I know I can write my own code (load batch, predict, load more) but I wonder if there is a "correct" tf solution.

Comment: yeah, I think you need to write your own function, there isn't an official way to do it